# Scala: '(' expected but identifier found

Tags: scala, if-statement, identifier

I'm new to Scala- but I'm an expert in Python-, and when I write a very simple if statement, I get an error.

Code:

```
val x=1
if x>0 then print("asdf")
```

The error:

```
'(' expected but identifier found.
if x>0 then print("asdf")
```

What is going on? Could this be an issue with my coding environment, IntelliJ?

Comment: What version? Maybe you're trying to run scala3 code using scala2? See https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/control-structures.html#the-ifthenelse-construct for syntax differences.

Answer (score 1):

The following will fix it: There is no `then` in Scala 2, and `x>0` should be enclosed in parenthesis.

```
if (x > 0) print("asdf")
```

Comment: this answer is correct for scala 2, but not for scala 3. If you check the [docs for control structures in scala](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/control-structures.html#the-ifthenelse-construct) you will see that the code provided is correct in scala 3.

Comment: Both answers certainly fix this, thank you.